# Visual Studio Project Template *.projitems not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-template

I have created a visual studio template which worked fine. But as soon I try to add a new project to my solution by using this new template I get the following error:

```
"The imported project "c:\users\xy\AppData\Local\Temp\Common\Shared\XY.projitems" was not found. Confirm 
that the expression in the import declaration "..\..\Common\Shared\XY.projitems" is correct and that the 
file exists on disk."c:\users\xy\AppData\Local\Temp\qfuczw4e.apk\Temp\MyTemplate1.csproj"
```

Background info:

My solution contains a shared project which is referenced in my project template

The import statement in *.csproj of my project template looks like this:

```
<Import Project="..\..\Common\Shared\XY.projitems" Label="Shared" />
```

- The *.projitems file exists related to the above relative path.
- The file does NOT exist in the above mentioned path "c:\users\xy\AppData\Local\Temp\qfuczw4e.apk\Temp\"

The error message is very confusing to me. Anybody have a hint for me?

### UPDATE

The project structure in which a new project will be created with the template is as follows:

```
Solution_XY

   - SharedProject

   - PluginsFolder
     - Project_1
     - Project_2
     - Project_3
```

The projects created are located in a special project folder within the solution. So Project_1 to Project_3 need to have a reference to the SharedProject when created by the template.

Comment: I think it’s caused by the differences of reference. I test by using [multi-project templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019) and error persists, I notice that if I create template only for Shared Project or the other project, they will work without error. Since shared project is [unique](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#shared-project-references), I may consider VS doesn’t support to create a project template which contains a reference to Shared Project.

Comment: thank you for your reply on this. yes you're right, it must be related to this as you mentioned. probably then I can forget about creating such a template since even a multi-project-template will not fit, because I cannot have the shared project within the project itself. because the projects based on this template will be created in the solution containing the shared project...se my updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this same problem, and there is no answer on here for it.
It is caused because parameter replacement is being done in a temporary folder, as you can see.  It's anyone's guess why they are checking path.

Either way, the fix is to have the [CreateInPlace](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/createinplace-visual-studio-templates.md#:%7E:text=CreateInPlace%20element%20%28Visual%20Studio%20templates%29%20Specifies%20whether%20to,to%20the%20specified%20location.%20%3CVSTemplate%3E%20%3CTemplateData%3E%20%3CCreateInPlace%3E%20Syntax) template data set to 'true'.

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    ...
    <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
  </TemplateData>
```

This was a real pain to figure this out. Hopefully it will help somebody.

The problem isn't related to it being a multi project template.
I solved this problem while making a multi project template.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your reply. helped alot, thx